# ChoiceBox does not populate until it is clicked 3 times

Tags: java, javafx

I have the problem, that my ChoiceBox only populates if it is clicked 3 times in a row. I really don't know why. I also don't know why it is successfull after exactly three clicks. In a similiar class this code works fine to populate the choiceBox (There are no problems with populating and updating of the ChoiceBox)

```
public class AuswertungController {

ProjektDAO project = new ProjektDAODBImpl();
MitarbeiterDAO mitarbeiter = new MitarbeiterDAODBImpl();
TaetigkeitDAO taetigkeit = new TaetigkeitDAODBImpl();
ObservableList<Taetigkeit> taetigkeitliste;
ObservableList<Mitarbeiter> mitarbeiterliste;
ObservableList<Projekt> projektliste;
private ObservableList<String> zwischenmitar;
private ObservableList<String> zwischenproj;

@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> choiceMitar;
```

With this method i populate my choiceMitar choiceBox

```
public void choiceMitarAktualisieren() {
    mitarbeiterliste = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mitarbeiter.getAllMitarbeiter());
    zwischenmitar = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for(Mitarbeiter m : mitarbeiterliste) {
        zwischenmitar.add(m.toString());
    }

    choiceMitar.setItems(zwischenmitar);
}
```

}

Comment: You would need to at least show what the event handlers for your components are, it's quite clear there is an issue with events somewhere.

Comment: If i click on my ChoiceBox, this method is called

Comment: Oh, then it's likely a non-trivial issue since you're trying to modify a choice box while it is being accessed (since the click's standard function is to open the choices list). It's likely a synchronization issue.

I don't know what the quality of the code is, but a quick google search found something like this: https://github.com/jidesoft/jidefx-oss/blob/master/module-common/src/main/java/jidefx/utils/LazyLoadUtils.java, you might want to look at it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. We don't know what all those third-party classes do nor how they're relevant to the problem at hand (if not relevant, don't include them in your example). Note you might even solve your problem while creating the example.

Comment: I have found the Error! After half an hour of thinking about every method i saw that I forgot to implement Initializable... Thank you for your possible solutions to my problem!